# Java best way to multihread save/load large amounts of data

Tags: java, multithreading, save

For a game I am writing, the world is saved as chunks. Each chunk (when saved) is just under 200kb (they are very large chunks). Whenever a world is loaded 121 chunks need to be loaded. Each one only takes a fraction of a second, but all those fractions add up and lead to taking several seconds.

This would be ok, but saving is even more important. When a player walks into new chunks, all the chunks out of range will be saved and unloaded. As each save takes a fraction of a second, I would get a lag spike of over a second every time the player moves chunks. For this reason, I hope to use Threads to save and load chunks so that a chunk can be saved/loaded while the game is still running.

I have no idea how I would implement such a thing though. So, if anyone could share a link to a tutorial or give some source code I could play with, that would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please explain your Question with some small Example...

Comment: If you need real-time gaming, you should bypass garbagee-collection with using dll functions. JNI.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik You can bypass the GC by creating less garbage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use memory mapped files and I would load as much as possible in as few files as possible (each files adds an overhead)

If you do this you can load/save GB in a fraction of a second.